# R Programming - ggplot and geom_bar - How to sort data by descending order?

Tags: r

I am new here in stackoverflow and also new in R. I have a question. How do you sort data using ggplot and geom_bar in **descending** order? Here is my code:

> ggplot(actions) +geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=reorder(Actions,Actions,length))) +coord_flip() + ylab("Count") +xlab("Actions")

Here is the output. Would be very grateful for your help. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnBLq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: `aes(x=reorder(Actions, Actions, function(x)-length(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorder your dataframe based on you chosen axis. Here is a working example with cars dataset.

```
df <- mtcars

df2 <- transform(df,
          cyl = reorder(cyl,order(mpg, decreasing = TRUE)))

p <- ggplot(df2) + 
                geom_bar(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg), stat = 'identity') +
                coord_flip() + 
                ylab("mpg") +
                xlab("cyl")

print(p)
```

[image: Sorted based on cyl, as that was on my x-axis originally]

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for your response. I'm still having issue on how to generate the chart. When you check it, it has only 1 dimension (Actions). Y-axis: Actions, X-axis: Count. When I translate your code to mine, I'm getting the "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". I don't know if the code is correct or what. Here is the code btw:

Comment: ggplot(actions) + geom_bar(aes(x=Actions[order(Actions,decreasing=TRUE)])) + coord_flip()